How to run SQL on Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab?
I am trying to load a database and operate with it with SQL on Jupyter notebooks. I am following the instructions but it doesn't seem to work because it won't run the command %sql:
!pip install ipython-sql sqlalchemy

%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///love4pets.db

The output of running this on Jupyter is:
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-sql in /home/alberto/pysql/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /home/alberto/pysql/lib/python3.12/site-packages (2.0.2)

… (many lines saying "requirement already satisfied)

The sql module is not an IPython extension.
UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found.

If the requirements are satisfied, why doesn't it run as expected?

Have you created a flle named sql.py somewhere?

No, why? I only have the database love4pets.db.

Comment on !pip install ipython-sql sqlalchemy: Please adopt the use of current approaches for a better experience in modern Jupyter. That should be %pip install....  The modern magic install command was added in 2019 to ensure installation run in notebook cell occurs in the correct environment where the kernel is running. Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with an install command run in a cell doesn't do that and by result was leading to confusion and issues. Please see ...

 here for expanded details and resources.

Thanks for replying, @Wayne! I tried with it and it's already installed using a fresh venv (named pysql): screenshot 1/2 2/2.
Using %pip gives me the "error: externally-managed-environment" message.

Yes, I should have pointed out better that it wouldn't help in this case since the information said it was already installed. By 'comment on !pip install' I was trying to indicate I was just making a comment about that line and trying to encourage you to adopt the currrent best practice and not foster others using outdated approaches by posting them as if they are the way to do things.

@Alberto This question was closed with an incorrect duplicate; I've re-closed it with two more suitable duplicates. It looks like there is a mismatch between the Python version associated with pip and the Python version used by Jupyter.  See the linked duplicates for details.
